# PostgreSQL CTE/Sub-Query with generate_series performance issues

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

=====  Updated Based on Feedback =====

Due to some initial questions seeking clarification, here is a really simple version of this.

```
WITH my_var AS ( 
    SELECT date '2016-01-01' as a_date          
    --, generate_series(1, 40) as numbers       
    )
Select generate_series(1, 100000) as numbers, my_var.a_date from my_var 

execution time: 411ms

"CTE Scan on my_var  (cost=0.01..5.03 rows=1000 width=4)"
"  CTE my_var"
"    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)"
```

Now if we uncomment the the generate_series in the

```
WITH my_var AS ( 
    SELECT date '2016-01-01' as a_date          
    , generate_series(1, 40) as numbers     
)
Select generate_series(1, 100000) as numbers, my_var.a_date from my_var 

execution time: 16201ms

"CTE Scan on my_var  (cost=5.01..5022.51 rows=1000000 width=4)"
"  CTE my_var"
"    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=0)"
```

The point being here is if the generate_series(1, 40) is only supposed to be executed once, why is does it take so long for the query to complete.  In this case, I didn't even use the 'number' set in the main query and it still took and extended amount of time to complete.

=====  Original Inquiry =====

I've run into an interesting performance issue with PostgreSQL 9.x using sub-queries and/or CTE.

...And to completely honest, I'm not too sure if this is a "bug" or just an user (i.e. Me) understanding of CTE/Sub-queries and or use of the generate_series function.

I've been writing some advanced and longer queries using CTE.  I've been using a technique where I've put a static variable such as dates into a master CTE which filters through all the additional queries. The idea is to make 1 set of changes rather than lots of them through a long query when you need to run it with different parameters.

An example of this is:

```
WITH dates AS ( 
   SELECT 
      date '2013-01-01' AS start_date, 
      date_trunc('month', current_date) AS end_date
)
SELECT * from dates, sometable where somedate between start_date and end_date

execution time:  ~650ms
```

So, it is my understanding that a CTE is run once, but after running into a performance issue, this is clearly not what is happening.  For example, if I modify the CTE to include a generate_series:

```
WITH dates AS ( 
   SELECT 
      date '2013-01-01' AS start_date, 
      date_trunc('month', current_date) AS end_date,
      generate_series(1, 10) AS somelist
)
SELECT * from dates, sometable where somedate between start_date and end_date 
   and myval in (somelist)

execution time:  ~23000ms
```

Due to some serious performance issues with this (thousands of times slower), I at first thought the generate_series() was assigning the somelist the "generate_series" function and then being executed as a subquery for every row in sometable in the main query. So to confirm this I modified the query is as follows:

```
WITH dates AS ( 
   SELECT 
      date '2013-01-01' AS start_date, 
      date_trunc('month', current_date) AS end_date--,
      --generate_series(1, 10) AS somelist
)
SELECT * from dates, sometable where somedate between start_date and end_date 
   and myval in (generate_series(1, 10))


execution time:  ~700ms
```

To my surprise, this was relatively fast (and only 10% slower). The generate_series as as sub-query is clearly not the issue.

So then went to the back to the original query and just added the generate_series but never used it in the main query.  here is that query.

```
WITH dates AS ( 
   SELECT 
      date '2013-01-01' AS start_date, 
      date_trunc('month', current_date) AS end_date,
      generate_series(1, 10) AS somelist
)
SELECT * from dates, sometable where somedate between start_date and end_date

execution time:  ~23000ms
```

This is clearly the the smoking gun... but I have no idea why or for that matter what is really going. Here are my questions:

In Summary, the use of the generate_series within a CTE or sub-query is consuming huge amounts of time/resources (even if the result isn't being used). I get the same results in both Postgres v9.3 and v9.5.  I'm table I running against has ~14 million rows.  The result set is only about 275K.

I'm clueless at this point, does anyone have any theories?  (... or is it a bug?)

Comment: Interesting question, but you need provide more info about `sometable` like index. Also will be good if you include the `explain analyze` of all query so we can understand what is doing the rdbms and compare between each query.

Comment: Please add table aliases to your queries and use them when referring to column names. It is completely vague where the expression stem from, it could even be a Carthesian product. ad instead of `SELECT * from dates, sometable` you could use the JOIN-syntax for extra readability.

Comment: @Juan - My point is it doesn't matter about indexes.  It doesn't event need to connect to a real table.  I'll post an update to show this.

Comment: @wildplasser - there isn't technically a join.  I'm adding a new example to show a simpler version of this.

Comment: `SELECT * from dates, sometable ...` **is** a join. A CTE is a TABLE expression; when used in a query, it *behaves* just like a table.

Comment: See updated section with examples you can run on your server.

Comment: It *appears* to be a bug. I'll post as an answer (for formatting)

Answer (score 2):

Experiment (I left out the dates, because they are just additional scalar constants)

```
EXPLAIN
WITH my_cte_b AS (
        SELECT generate_series(1, 40) as b_number
        )
, my_cte_c AS (
        SELECT generate_series(1, 1000) AS c_number
        )
Select
        my_cte_b.b_number
        , my_cte_c.c_number
FROM my_cte_b
JOIN my_cte_c ON (1=1)
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
                                 QUERY PLAN                            
------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=5.01..10020.01 rows=1000000 width=8)
   CTE my_cte_b
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..2.50 rows=1000 width=0)
   CTE my_cte_c
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..2.50 rows=1000 width=0)
   ->  CTE Scan on my_cte_b  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=4)
   ->  CTE Scan on my_cte_c  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=4)
(7 rows)
```

But `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` gives the correct result:

```
-----------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=5.01..10020.01 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=0.029..8.953 rows=40000 loops=1)
   CTE my_cte_b
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..2.50 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.019 rows=40 loops=1)
   CTE my_cte_c
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..2.50 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.095 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on my_cte_b  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.021..0.040 rows=40 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on my_cte_c  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.104 rows=1000 loops=40)
 Planning time: 0.042 ms
 Execution time: 25.206 ms
(9 rows)
```

, So the problem appears to be in the estimate, not in the execution.

---

As a bonus: you *can* hint (or: *fool*) the planner by putting a `LIMIT xx` in the CTEs:

---

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH my_cte_b AS (
        SELECT generate_series(1, 40) as b_number
        LIMIT 40
        )
, my_cte_c AS (
        SELECT generate_series(1, 1000) AS c_number
        LIMIT 10000
        )
Select
        my_cte_b.b_number
        , my_cte_c.c_number
FROM my_cte_b
JOIN my_cte_c ON (1=1)
        ;

                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=2.60..408.00 rows=40000 width=8) (actual time=0.019..9.347 rows=40000 loops=1)
   CTE my_cte_b
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.10 rows=40 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.018 rows=40 loops=1)
           ->  Result  (cost=0.00..2.50 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.013 rows=40 loops=1)
   CTE my_cte_c
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..2.50 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.241 rows=1000 loops=1)
           ->  Result  (cost=0.00..2.50 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.134 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on my_cte_b  (cost=0.00..0.40 rows=40 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.036 rows=40 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on my_cte_c  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.112 rows=1000 loops=40)
 Planning time: 0.096 ms
 Execution time: 10.693 ms
(11 rows)
```

My conclusion: the planner has no statistics on the CTEs (they dont contain any references to physical tables), and just makes a guess (1000). This guess can be overruled by putting a LIMIT inside the CTEs.

---

BTW: since PG-11 (or so) the restrinction (cte IS ALWAYS EXECUTED ONCE) has been removed. iff there are no side-effects.